# Unexpected Behavior in Python Condition - No Runtime Error

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, comparison

I'm encountering unexpected behavior in a Python code snippet and I'm having trouble understanding why it doesn't result in a runtime error. I expected it to raise an error, but it's not doing so.

Here's the code:

```
s = "scscds"
if s != '' or len(s) > s[3:5]:
    print("csd")
```

The conditions in this code check whether the string `s` is not empty and whether the length of `s` is greater than a sliced substring. The sliced substring is obtained from `s[3:5]`, which results in "cd," with a length of 2. The original string `s` has a length of 6.

I would expect the code to raise a runtime error when comparing the length of the entire string with a substring. However, it runs without errors and prints "csd."

Can someone explain why this code behaves this way and why it doesn't result in an error?

I was expecting this code to raise a runtime error because it compares the length of the entire string `s` to a sliced substring obtained from `s[3:5]`.

Based on common expectations, comparing the length of a string to another string should result in an error because they have different data types. However, the code runs without errors and prints "csd."